# How does append function work in Swift?

Tags: ios, string, swift, append

Can someone explain me what is wrong with this statement.

```
var someString = "Welcome"
someString.append("!")
```

However this works when I replace the code with,

```
var someString = "Welcome"
let exclamationMark : Character = "!"
someString.append(exclamationMark)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

In Swift, there is no character literal (such as `'c'` in C-derived languages), there are only `String` literals.

Then, you have two functions defined on `String`s: `append`, to append a single character, and `extend`, to append a whole String. So this works:

```
var someString = "Welcome"
someString.extend("!")
```

If you really want to use `append`, you can force a one-char `String` literal to be turned into a `Character` either by calling `Character`'s constructor:

```
someString.append(Character("!"))
```

or by using a type conversion:

```
someString.append("!" as Character)
```

or by using a type annotation as you did with an extra variable:

```
let exclamationMark: Character = "!"
someString.append(exclamationMark)
```

Answer (score 0):

`String` has 2 overloaded `append(_:)`

```
     mutating func append(x: UnicodeScalar)
     mutating func append(c: Character)
```

and both `Character` and `UnicodeScalar` conforms `UnicodeScalarLiteralConvertible`

```
enum Character : ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralConvertible, Equatable, Hashable, Comparable {

    /// Create an instance initialized to `value`.
    init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: Character)
}

struct UnicodeScalar : UnicodeScalarLiteralConvertible {

    /// Create an instance initialized to `value`.
    init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: UnicodeScalar)
}
```

`"!"` in this case is a `UnicodeScalarLiteral`. So, the compiler can not determine `"!"` is `Character` or `UnicodeScalar`, and which `append(_:)` method should be invoked. That's why you must specify it explicitly.

---

You can see: `"!"` can be a UnicodeScalar literal by this code:

```
struct MyScalar: UnicodeScalarLiteralConvertible {
    init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: UnicodeScalar) {
        println("unicode \(value)")
    }
}

"!" as MyScalar // -> prints "unicode !"
```

Comment: Formally speaking, `"!"` is actually a `String` literal that contains a single Unicode scalar value. The header comments for `UnicodeScalarLiteralConvertible` state this: “Conforming types can be initialized with string literals containing a single Unicode scalar value”.

Comment: Actually (sorry to be picky—I would edit my comment, but cannot any more), `"!"` is precisely *not* a `UnicodeScalar`, otherwise `someString.append("!")` would compile right away.