# How to convert Character type annotation to String type annotation?

Tags: swift, string, type-conversion, character, type-annotation

The purpose of converting a Character type annotation to String type annotation is for the purpose of concatenating.

There are some answers [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495802/how-does-append-function-work-in-swift/28495888#28495888), however it does not help because it only shows how to convert from String to Character.

I have tried to do it with `String()` constructor, but it did not work.

Let's say I have this snippet of code.

```
var name = "Ton"
var nameLastCha: Character = "y"

name += nameLastCha
```

The above code would return an error saying `Cannot convert value of type "Character" to expected argument type "String"`

However, if I use `append()` the concatenation of `name` and `nameLastCha` work just fine.

```
var name = "Ton"
var nameLastCha: Character = "y"

name.append(nameLastCha)
```

The result is `Tony` which works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` and `Character` are different types. `String` is a collection (array) of `Character`s, so that is why you can `.append()` it. And can just add the character as another string based on that character.

```
name += String(nameLastCha)
```

Comment: I just realized that if I use String() the wrong way. I declared nameLastCha += String(nameLastCha) // this does not work

Comment: Of course `nameLastCha += String(nameLastCha)` won't work because you're trying to add a `String` to a `Character`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to convert Character annotation to String annotation :-

```
var name = "Ton"
        let nameLastCha: Character = "y"

        name += "\(nameLastCha)"
```

Comment: Good suggestion! Thanks!